# how to show Real-time data on dateAxis in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, linechart

[Graph Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKxSW.jpg)

I just wonder that i wanna make program that show real-time data on DateAxis using javafx chart.

now, i made realtime chart but it doesn't match with DateAxis.
I know there is CategoryAxis and NumberAxis and when i searched in Stackoverflow, i need to use NumberAxis for setTickLabelFormatter.

Now, i got date (string type) from database and change it to long type.
but i don't know how to insert these data to LineChart xAxis. at first, i need to sorting these data by date and insert to xAxis.

In my code, there are many Errors.
I need to the way for solving problem not for errors.
I have no idea for resolving this.
Please help me.

This is code for data:

```
while(searchCursor.hasNext())  
             {
                 Document element = searchCursor.next();
                 String datetime = element.getString("Date");
                 Double value = Double.parseDouble(element.getString("Value"));
                 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            try {
                date = format.parse(datetime);
                longdate = date.getTime();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

             Datalist.add(new GraphData(longdate, value));

             Collections.sort(Datalist, new Comparator<GraphData>() {
                 @Override
                 public int compare(GraphData date1, GraphData date2)
                 {
                     return date1.Date.compareTo(date2.Date);
                 }
             });

             dateAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(dateAxis)
             {

                 @Override
                 public String toString(Number object)
                 {
                     DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

                     LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(object.longValue()), ZoneId.systemDefault());
                     String formattedDateTime = dateTime.format(formatter);
                     return formattedDateTime;

                 }
             });

             series[i].getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>((Datalist.get(eachdatacnt).Date), Datalist.get(eachdatacnt).Value));
             eachdatacnt++;
         }

         series[i].setName(SelectedEndpointNameList.get(i).toString());
         lineChart.setAnimated(false);
         lineChart.getData().add(series[i]);
         lineChart.setAxisSortingPolicy(LineChart.SortingPolicy.X_AXIS);
     }
```

Comment: What are these errors? Please post them, too.

Comment: there is no syntax error but it's not my wanted.
I want to put sorted date into xAxis

Comment: I want to insert date as "HH:mm:ss"